# Web resource with different genres as a graph (and samples)

Tags: genre, similar-artists

I remember a page (flash based?, it was like 7 years ago i visited it) where the genres were displayed as a graph, with edges between related genres, and I think you could listen to samples on each of the nodes (or maybe it was only artist suggestions)

It was a great tool to discover genres close to the ones you like, and you could traverse further out in your comfort zone.

It could also have been that it was not genres but artists as nodes, and similar artists as nodes with relations, but they were clustered in similar genres.

Anyone know what tool/site I'm referring to? Are there any pages like this today?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an identification question asking for a specific website. It is unlikely to be useful to future readers.

Comment: See this meta post: http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/34/identify-this-song-genre-artist-on-topic . It's not specially about identifying websites, but I believe its arguments still apply to this question.

Comment: @Kevin, added question about if there are any pages like this today, don't know if that would make it eligible for reopening, but worth a shot.

Comment: @Kevin I'm not familiar with the website, but if it exists, it seems like it would be a valuable general resource for music fans.

Comment: I also remember this website, i know we used this to listen to music at work some years ago, but also cant remember the name. So at least it can confirm it existed, i hope someone knows about it, it was a really nice site to hear some new musics from genres you like...

Comment: @kl78 yes, both new music from known genres, and a good way to explore neighboring genres

Answer (score 3):

I remembered which site we used some years ago. It was [musicovery](http://musicovery.com/).
It still exists, has changed a bit over the time, but basic functionality is still available there. You can select genre, time and mood and then get matching songs by clicking on nodes. I remember they als had a graph some years ago, but could not find it today, maybe they have removed it, or you mean another site like this.

Comment: Similar, but looking more for the interconnections between genres

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it'll be of any use but what you described made me think of [music map](http://www.music-map.com/) and [musicroamer](http://www.musicroamer.com/#/)